# HttpServletRequest not returning entire cookie

Tags: servlets, cookies, jersey

My HttpServletRequest.getCookies() is not returning the whole cookie value.
The cookie value is another key-value pair so perhaps that's messing up the parsing. I need to know how to get around this.

So here's the background. I'm using the new apache2.4 mod_auth_form which does authentication by setting the username and password in a cookie.
The cookie looks something like this:
"session=private-user=myUser&private-pw=myPass"

I have a Proxy set up on Apache so that certain REST calls are passed through to a tomcat service, where I have a Jersey REST class waiting for them.

I can see the cookie in my browser. I can also see the full cookie in php.
However, in my java class, the HttpServletRequest has the "session" cookie but the value is simply "private-user", not "private-user=myUser&private-pw=myPass" as I expect.

My best guess is that the key-value pairs with = and & symbols is messing up the parsing. How can I get at the full, raw cookie value?

Here's my java code if it matters:

```
private String getAuthenticatedUser(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        String user = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use URLEncoder to encode the value before you set it in cookie.

```
String s = new String("private-user=myUser&private-pw=myPass");
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(s);
```

and use URLDecoder to decode it back to the original value

```
URLDecoder.decode(encoded);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control of this. As I mentioned, the apache mod_auth_form module sets the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this using Jersey's @CookieParam annotation.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public Response myRestCall(@CookieParam("session") String sessionValue) {
  System.out.println(sessionValue);
}
```

Jersey seems to do a better job of parsing this type of key-value cookie and returned "private-user=myUser&private-pw=myPass" as I expected.

Comment: This doesnt explain how it solves the issue. you have just used Annotation in the place of manually getting the value from the cookie

Comment: You're right. It solved my problem because I was able to work around it. And this solution is actually more elegant than using HttpServletRequest for me.
But I would still like to know how to get the full cookie out of the HttpServletRequest if you know how.